# Convert datetime field in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a datetime field which has a value like this `5/11/2010 12:04:20 PM` .... I am converting this field `convert(varchar, dbo.Clients.CreatedDate,103) as CreatedDate` and i get  the result as `11/5/2010`..... But how to get `11/5/2010 12:04 PM`.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different formatting style to include the time component.

For example:

```
convert(varchar, dbo.Clients.CreatedDate, 131)
```

All styles are documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: `28/05/1431 12:04:20:000PM` i dont want sec and millisec

Comment: Sorry, that's a different calendar system anyhow.  Best solution then may be either to use a canonical format (120) or split up the date into parts (using the DATEPART) function and cast each to a separate varchar in your desired order.